# Calculating Berry phase for parallel transport of vector around closed path on sphere.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I am following the text [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0508236v1.pdf) which explains that we are transporting a vector $\mathbf{v}$ around a closed circular loop (C) on a sphere under the constraints $\mathbf{e}_3\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$ and $\mathbf{e}_3 \times d\mathbf{v}=0$ where $\mathbf{e}_3$ is the local normal vector to the surface of the sphere. At each point we can write $\mathbf{v}$ in the local coordinate frame $[\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2]$ as

$$\mathbf{v}(t)=\cos\alpha(t)\mathbf{e}_1(t)+\sin\alpha(t)\mathbf{e}_2(t)$$

where $t$ parameterises the curve. Then, apparently, by using the constraints and this expanded form of $\mathbf{v}$ we realise that

$$d\alpha=\mathbf{e}_1\cdot d\mathbf{e}_2 \equiv \omega_{21}$$

but it seems like there's a bunch of omitted steps to get to this result which I don't understand. Subsequently the total angle $\alpha(C)$ is the integral of $\omega_{21}$ and is then linked to geometrical phases etc etc but I need to understand the omitted steps first.

Thanks very much for any help

Comment: You can't have both of those conditions: $ \lVert a \rVert^2 \lVert b \rVert^2 = \lvert a \cdot b \rvert^2 + \lVert a \times b \rVert^2$, so both products can only be zero if one of the vectors is zero.

Comment: Typo corrected.

Comment: Just a general remark about the literature around Hall effects and topological insulators: they seem to miss the important work by Barry Simon, which is acknowledged in Berry's original work (that I also recommend) http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.51.2167

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the paper, the actual condition is $e_3 \times dv = 0$. We compute:
$$ dv = d\alpha ( -e_1\sin{\alpha}+e_2\cos{\alpha} )+de_1 \cos{\alpha}+de_2 \sin{\alpha} $$
Now dot with $e_1$. Since $dv \parallel e_3$, we have $e_1 \cdot dv=0$, and
$$ 0 = d\alpha ( -e_1 \cdot e_1 \sin{\alpha}+e_1 \cdot e_2\cos{\alpha} )+ e_1 \cdot de_1 \cos{\alpha}+ e_1 \cdot de_2 \sin{\alpha}. $$
We know $e_1 \cdot e_2= 0$ (definition), and
$$ 1 = e_i \cdot e_i \implies 0 = 2e_i \cdot de_i, $$
so the equation cancels down to
$$ 0 = (-d\alpha +e_1 \cdot de_2) \sin{\alpha}, $$
which implies the given equation. Similarly, dotting with $e_2$ gives the same thing multiplied by $\cos{\alpha}$, so $d\alpha = e_1 \cdot de_2$ for any value of $\alpha$.

Comment: ah brilliant, i understand the steps now thank you